# Smart way to analyze HTTP header fields in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http-headers

I programmed for Android with Java and its standard library has the classes Header and HeaderElement through which it is possible to analyze the HTTP headers in a smart way. These are very useful because avoid the user to parse the header values (which may be different and complex).

These are their official documentation pages, it is clear the meaning of the methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/Header.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HeaderElement.html

Is there something similar for iOS in Objective-C? If I receive a response (typed as NSHTTPURLResponse) do I have to parse its header fields manually?

I ask this because the only method which I see for retrieving a header of a NSHTTPURLResponse is

```
- (NSDictionary *)allHeaderFields
```

which simply returns a dictionary with NSString objects as values.

### EDIT, example added

If we take, for example, the Cache-Control header of a response, it may have the following syntax:

```
"public"                               
| "private" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ]
| "no-cache" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ]
| "no-store"                             
| "no-transform"                         
| "must-revalidate"                      
| "proxy-revalidate"                     
| "max-age" "=" delta-seconds            
| "s-maxage" "=" delta-seconds           
| cache-extension
```

where

```
[] means optional
1# means one ore more
```

you understand that it may be complex to parse headers manually.

Comment: What does "analyze the HTTP headers in a smart way" mean?

Comment: It means, if I have for example the header Cache-Control with the value "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate", I want a way for easily analyze all the parts of the header value. It may appear stupid but there are header fields with a more complex syntax.

Comment: As long as you are talking about those standard headers, you actually should not need to care as the OS will do that for you.

Comment: Please provide a link to those Android classes so we can see how they work.

Comment: I tried to read the content of the headers in a response and I obtained: the value "private, max-age=0" for the Cache-Control header, the value "1; mode=block" for the X-XSS-Protection header... what do you mean with "the OS will do that for you"?

Comment: At the end I found nothing, then I wrote my own classes Header and HeaderElement... If someone who need these in future will pass from here ask them to me.